# How to pipeline the (renamed or calculated measure) in mongodb aggregate project operator

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Can i refer to a renamed field (page_views in the below query) again in the same project operator and use the same to calculate a different value? (Note: The query below doesn't work as expected)

```
db.article.aggregate(
{ $project : { 
title : 1 , 
page_views : { add:["$views", 10] } ,
bar : "$other.foo", 
perUserPageViews : { divide:["$page_views", "$user"] }
}}
);
```

My usecase is to calculate a stage value (a+b) and then calculate (a+b) - c. I require both the values to be in the output. Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by adding two [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operators as follows. Also in your code, you forgot to add $ sign before the add & divide operators.

```
db.agg.aggregate(
    {$project : {
        page_views : { "$add":["$views", 10]}}
    },
    {$project : {
        title:1, 
        bar:"$other.foo", 
        page_views : 1, 
        perUserPageViews : {"$divide" : ["$page_views","$user"]}}
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed out the page_views:1 in the second project that I was trying.